# how the internet connecting all clints via server?

Tags: web

can any explain me about how the server responds if we click the button in browser using PHP script then which situation we use JAVASCRIPT and which situation we have to use PHP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about how it works, I'll suggest to google about HTTP protocol, POST and GET methods.

Usually, you use JavaScript to send request to a server when you want it to be AJAX, ie when you want to send request to server and receive response without reloading page. And you use PHP when you have form in your HTML (like login or registration form), and you send it to server in one request to go to another page